# Rails form validaiton issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I don't get why the form is not validated. create method is executed even if there are no values in the text fields here is the code that I use

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movies = Movie.find(:all)
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to "http://localhost:3000/movies/new/"
    end
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :year

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :year

end
```

Here is the view

```
Enter new movie information 
<%= form_for @movie do |f|%><br />
    Title <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
    Year <%= f.text_field :year %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<hr />
List of all movies<br />
<% if !@movies.blank? %>
  <% for item in @movies %>
    <%= item.id %>&nbsp;<%=  item.title %> (<%= item.year %>) <br />
  <% end %>
<% else %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: The controller action should always run when you post the form. It's `Movie#save` that returns false if the validation fails, but you don't seem to handle it at all. This code will simply try to render the create view if validation fails. Is that the case?

Comment: `redirect_to "http://localhost:3000/movies/new"` is more flexible if you change it to `redirect_to new_movie_path` as this will work when you move to a production domain. [Routing paths and URLs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

Comment: Do you mean the a blank record gets saved on create without validation?

Comment: @IanFleeton when I change it to new_movie_path I get 
undefined local variable or method `new_movie_path'
error

Comment: @PriteshJ, no. Blank record is not created

Comment: @dorofr I assumed that you had `resources :movies` as a line in your routes.rb file. You may want to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller

```
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to new_movie_path  # You sure you what to redirect this to new after success? 
                                  # redirect as per your project requirement on success
    else
      render :new # render new with errors displayed
    end
  end
```

In View added error display message when validation fails

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f|%>
  <% if @movie.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% @movie.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <br />
    Title <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
    Year <%= f.text_field :year %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<hr />
List of all movies<br />
<% if !@movies.blank? %>
  <% for item in @movies %>
    <%= item.id %>&nbsp;<%=  item.title %> (<%= item.year %>) <br />
  <% end %>
 <% else %>
   No Movies found.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation occurs when you call @movie.save. Because @movie is not valid, #save will return false and @movie.errors will be populated.

This validation does not prevent the form being submitted (and #create being executed). For that you want to look at validations with JavaScript/jQuery and Rails.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean with this "Because @movie is not valid" ?

Comment: If you leave the title blank, the validation will fail when you call @movie.save, because you have said `validates_presence_of :title`. After this, @movie.save will return false and @movie.errors will contain the list of error messages (so you can show them when you re-display the form). This is what the validation does.